# How do I retrieve the full (extended) tweet with the Twitter API V2 in Postman/Python?

Tags: python, json, http, twitter

I am conducting my master's thesis and paid for the basic access to the Twitter API. I know Twitter is not ideal for academic research anymore, but since I am going to only look into a few specific accounts, I was told it might work fine. I paid for basic access (100$ per month).

However, now I am trying to retrieve tweets (which I can do up to 10.000 per month). However, the JSON output I get after having entered the relevant information in Postman is not providing me with the full tweet if the characters are over a certain number.

Ideally, I would be able to do so. In the old Twitter v1.1, there was an option to specify: "tweet_mode='extended'", at least when using Tweepy (although Tweepy seemingly does not work anymore).

Does anyone have a solution for this simple, yet very annoying problem? I figure I am not the only one needing the *full* tweets when scraping?

My GET code is: https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/tweets?max_results=100&expansions=author_id,entities.mentions.username&tweet.fields=created_at,attachments,lang,public_metrics&user.fields=created_at,name&=exclude=retweets

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

For Tweets exceeding 280 characters, you'll need to include `note_tweet` in the `tweet.fields` parameter. When a tweet is in excess of this limit, the response would include the `note_tweet.text` attribute, which is specifically described in [the documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets) as containing "*The text for Tweets longer than 280 characters.*":

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/tweets?max_results=100&expansions=author_id,entities.mentions.username&tweet.fields=created_at,attachments,lang,public_metrics,note_tweet&user.fields=created_at,name&=exclude=retweets
```

Comment: I got that command to work - that is simply amazing. I thought I had looked all over Twitter's own documentation pages as well as SO, Google and more but apparently not.